# Illegal string offset in PHP multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

sorry by almost "repost" question. A few days ago i have a problem with a multidimensional array ([PHP multidimensional array x HasOffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38054835/php-multidimensional-array-x-hasoffers)) and now i'm getting some trouble to access info from another array.

I'm mading a API Call to export some data from a database. I export some fields and see an multidimensional array, but when i put it on a loop i get this error:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Offer' in /home/track374/public_html/the-ybox.tech/getStats_table.php on line 71
Warning: Illegal string offset 'conversions' in /home/track374/public_html/the-ybox.tech/getStats_table.php on line 71
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Stat' in /home/track374/public_html/the-ybox.tech/getStats_table.php on line 71
Warning: Illegal string offset 'conversions' in /home/track374/public_html/the-ybox.tech/getStats_table.php on line 71
```

This is the API call code with the loop:

```
<?php
    // Specify API URL
    define('HASOFFERS_API_URL', 'https://api.hasoffers.com/Apiv3/json');

    // Specify method arguments
    $args = array(
        'NetworkId' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
        'Target' => 'Report',
        'Method' => 'getStats',
        'NetworkToken' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
        'fields' => array(
            'Stat.conversions',
            'Offer.name'
        ),
        'groups' => array(
            'Stat.affiliate_id'
        ),
        'page' => '3',
        'data_start' => '2016-06-28',
        'data_end' => '2016-06-29'
    );

    // Initialize cURL
    $curlHandle = curl_init();

    // Configure cURL request
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, HASOFFERS_API_URL . '?' . http_build_query($args));

    // Make sure we can access the response when we execute the call
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Execute the API call
    $jsonEncodedApiResponse = curl_exec($curlHandle);

    // Ensure HTTP call was successful
    if($jsonEncodedApiResponse === false) {
        throw new \RuntimeException(
            'API call failed with cURL error: ' . curl_error($curlHandle)
        );
    }

    // Clean up the resource now that we're done with cURL
    curl_close($curlHandle);

    // Decode the response from a JSON string to a PHP associative array
    $apiResponse = json_decode($jsonEncodedApiResponse, true);

    // Make sure we got back a well-formed JSON string and that there were no
    // errors when decoding it
    $jsonErrorCode = json_last_error();
    if($jsonErrorCode !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        throw new \RuntimeException(
            'API response not well-formed (json error code: ' . $jsonErrorCode . ')'
        );
    }

    // Print out the response details
    if($apiResponse['response']['status'] === 1) {
        // No errors encountered
        //echo 'API call successful';
        //echo PHP_EOL; 
        //echo print_r($apiResponse['response']['data'], true);
        //echo PHP_EOL;
        echo "<table border='1' width='100%'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td bgcolor='#ccc'>ID</td><td bgcolor='#ccc'>Nome da campanha</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        // Loop through Array
        foreach ($apiResponse['response']['data'] as $data) {
           echo "<tr><td>" . $data['Offer']['conversions'] . "</td><td>" . utf8_decode($data['Stat']['conversions']) . "</td></tr>";
        }

        echo "</table>";
    }
    else {
        // An error occurred
        echo 'API call failed (' . $apiResponse['response']['errorMessage'] . ')';
        echo PHP_EOL;
        echo 'Errors: ' . print_r($apiResponse['response']['errors'], true);
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
?>
```

And this is the multidimensional result:

```
Array ( [page] => 3 [current] => 50 [count] => 119 [pageCount] => 3 [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Stat] => Array ( [conversions] => 32 [affiliate_id] => 1291 ) [Offer] => Array ( [name] => Maria - BR ) ) [1] => Array ( [Stat] => Array ( [conversions] => 34 [affiliate_id] => 1000 ) [Offer] => Array ( [name] => Englishtown - BR ) ) [2] => Array ( [Stat] => Array ( [conversions] => 38 [affiliate_id] => 1056 ) [Offer] => Array ( [name] => Englishtown - BR ) ) [3] => Array ( [Stat] => Array ( [conversions] => 39 [affiliate_id] => 1052 ) [Offer] => Array ( [name] => Englishtown - BR ) ) [4] => Array ( [Stat] => Array ( [conversions] => 53 [affiliate_id] => 1228 ) [Offer] => Array ( [name] => Natura Consultora CND - BR ) ) [5] => Array ( [Stat] => Array ( [conversions] => 53 [affiliate_id] => 1513 ) [Offer] => Array ( [name] => Englishtown - BR ) ) [6] => Array ( [Stat] => Array ( [conversions] => 53 [affiliate_id] => 1456 ) [Offer] => Array ( [name] => Tara - MX ) ) [7] => Array ( [Stat] => Array ( [conversions] => 58 [affiliate_id] => 1465 ) [Offer] => Array ( [name] => Vsepo49 - RU ) ) [8] => Array ( [Stat] => Array ( [conversions] => 60 [affiliate_id] => 1539 ) [Offer] => Array ( [name] => Trilhonario - BR ) ) [9] => Array ( [Stat] => Array ( [conversions] => 71 [affiliate_id] => 1130 ) [Offer] => Array ( [name] => Englishtown - BR ) ) [10] => Array ( [Stat] => Array ( [conversions] => 90 [affiliate_id] => 1505 ) [Offer] => Array ( [name] => Englishtown - BR ) ) [11] => Array ( [Stat] => Array ( [conversions] => 107 [affiliate_id] => 1318 ) [Offer] => Array ( [name] => Proteste - BR ) ) [12] => Array ( [Stat] => Array ( [conversions] => 121 [affiliate_id] => 1404 ) [Offer] => Array ( [name] => Trilhonario - MX ) ) [13] => Array ( [Stat] => Array ( [conversions] => 237 [affiliate_id] => 1040 ) [Offer] => Array ( [name] => Englishtown - BR ) ) [14] => Array ( [Stat] => Array ( [conversions] => 268 [affiliate_id] => 1064 ) [Offer] => Array ( [name] => Turma da MÃ´nica - BR ) ) [15] => Array ( [Stat] => Array ( [conversions] => 350 [affiliate_id] => 1248 ) [Offer] => Array ( [name] => Proteste - BR ) ) [16] => Array ( [Stat] => Array ( [conversions] => 540 [affiliate_id] => 1046 ) [Offer] => Array ( [name] => Trilhonario - BR ) ) [17] => Array ( [Stat] => Array ( [conversions] => 720 [affiliate_id] => 1066 ) [Offer] => Array ( [name] => Englishtown - BR ) ) [18] => Array ( [Stat] => Array ( [conversions] => 823 [affiliate_id] => 1208 ) [Offer] => Array ( [name] => Proteste - BR ) ) ) [dbSource] => branddb )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code

```
foreach ($apiResponse['response']['data'] as $data) {
   echo "<tr><td>" . $data['Offer']['conversions'] . "</td><td>" . utf8_decode($data['Stat']['conversions']) . "</td></tr>";
}
```

assumes that every element in the child element has the `Offer` Property which in turn has the `conversions` property

Looking at the first few elements it's obvious where the problem is

```
[Offer] => Array ( [name] => Maria - BR ) ...
```

I think you meant to access `$data['Offer']['name']` instead of `$data['Offer']['conversions']`

Update in your loop to `foreach ($apiResponse['response']['data']['data'] as $data)`

Comment: Nope, i've tried before. Still get Illegal string offset 'Offer' and Illegal string offset 'name'

Comment: Sorry it has to be $apiResponse['response']['data']['data']. See updated code

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!!

Comment: I'm happy I could help. Happy coding :)